# Blank screen on resume (radeon card)

Tags: ati, compiz, radeon, resume

This is an old problem: sometimes disappears, sometimes returns.
I have a notebook with an ATI RADEON HD6320.

Using the opensource driver, everything works fine, except the resume after suspend: the screen remains blank and the only solution is restart the system.

fglrx is NOT a workaround: it is slower and brings problems with chrome (furthermore: why use closed source?).

I had no problems with 14.04 and 14.10 till one month ago, when the problem returned. Now i'm using 15.04, but the problem is still present.

I made some test, and IMHO the problem is in compiz.
So i made a (stupid) workaround. From a terminal:

1. kill compiz;
2. run pm-suspend;
3. restart compiz (from terminal);

I needed a little script, because after you kill compiz, you cannot write in your terminal. So my script is:

```
sudo ls # does nothing. Simply authorizes sudo.
killall compiz #kill compiz
sleep 5 # A little timeout to let the 'kill compiz' propagate
sudo pm-suspend # the real suspend
nohup compiz --replace > ~/compiz.log & # restarts compiz after resume.
```

It is ugly, but it is working 100% of times.

But is possible to use this workaround also when closing the lid, or when selecting "Suspend" from the Ubuntu Menu?

Comment: Sorry!!! Today, after two days, the workaround stopped to work. Don't know why... :(